# How to use injection with static @AfterClass

Tags: java, static, junit4, jboss-arquillian

I'm using a JUnit 4 test case and I want to use the `@AfterClass` annotation. To use it, the method using it must be static. And inside this very method, I want to use my `@Inject`ed objects.

But seems they cannot be static, i.e. they are null during runtime of the test if they are static. Actually, I want to delete certain database objects after all my tests have been run and I don't want to use `@After`.

How can I solve this problem? The only thing I can think of is to run the test cases alphabetically and make `zzz()` apply the logic I want.

Not using Spring, using Arquillian and deploying an ear to the server when testing

Comment: What u have tried so far ? Have u get any error ? Post them too.

Comment: Have you created the database in a method annotated with `@BeforeClass`? Probably you should store the table names in a static Collection variable.

Comment: My database connection (which is what I assume you mean) is created in a static method being called from my `@Before setUp()` method. This is far from optimal but there I faced the same problem. @OO7 I get a NPE when injecting static

Comment: You mean u want to access methods of injected object & the object is null ? To avoid this you can use `ternary operator` or `insteanceof` checking for Null object.

Comment: ô.O As I said, my injected object will always be null if it is static. But @AfterClass requires the method to be static

Comment: Will u elaborate this *they are null during runtime of the test if they are static.* I m confused with line ?

Comment: Inject as usual and set some static class field with the injected value, then use the static fields in @AfterClass?

Comment: You come back to the original problem: if I assign the static var to the injected var, I cannot do this in @BeforeClass. And to have this on the very first testcase, I need to run alphabetically and call this in `@Test public void aaaa()`. Or how is it possible else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly: database-involved unit testing is not so trivial, due to completely different nature unit tests (being independent of each other by definition) and databases (being inherently stateful).

Your approach with deleting certain database objects after all tests is generally not recommended.
In most cases far better approach is to:

1. Setup database into known state before **each** single test (*reason: tests are easier to manage, and do not interfere with each other*).
2. Leave the database state as it is (*reason: the ability to inspect "by hand" DB state is extremely useful when some tests have failed*).

To achieve above goals there are some tools. One is excellent [Arquillian Persistence Extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence) for database population. And another is [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/) (this is my favourite).

---

**Also alternative exists**

If using additional tool is not an option for you, then you should know that Arquillian’s JUnit integration provides an handy `@InSequence` annotation that can be used to set an explicit order of tests execution.

```
@Test
@InSequence(1)
public void place_order_should_add_order() {

    // some logic here
}

@Test
@InSequence(2)
public void order_should_be_persistent() {
    // some logic here that depends on the previous test-case 
}
```

This is far better than relying on the alphabetical order of the names of methods.

Also please note that above methods are not static, so you can use inside them whatever objects injected by the container - like `DataSource` or `EntityManager` etc.

Comment: why is it not recommend to delete my test objects from the DB after all tests ran? What is state-of-the-art to create the DB connection? I don't want to do this in `setUp()`/`@InSequence(1)` since my general `setUp()` where all testcases inherit from already needs a connection

Comment: @dasLort Your **first question** is answered above. Please read point two. Answering your **second question**: your intuition is good, the best way would be to create DB connection once, before all tests. **But** the exact solution depends what tools you are using (JPA or plain JDBC, remote Arquillian adapter or embedded, exact app server etc).  
You may find these [arquillian examples](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-examples/) extremely useful.